# Checking for server side app notifications in the background, in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

When I say notifications, I mean custom app notifications, so not iOS notifications. Notifications like Facebook's notification tab. Basically I want to check if a user has new friend requests, or if someone has commented on their posts, then load this data into a TableView which is displayed in my Notifications tab.

I wondering how I go about continually checking for these notifications from my server. Obviously I shouldn't check on a single tab bar's view controller, such as the NotificationsViewController. So I'm thinking should this type of functionality be performed in the AppDelegate?

And how do I seamlessly perform a request in the background, then have my Notifications tab catch the response, and parse it, so I can display a notifications badge. A snippet of Swift code, and where I should be placing it would be really helpful!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use silent push notification, it will inform your app that something new happened without showing the alert to user (send it from your server), perform repeated request in background is very energy consuming and does not advised, also it wont work if your app is not openning. To store it then can just use `NSUserDefault` or `CoreData`

Comment: Then read it from CoreData? Some of the notifications are going to be locally generated as well, for example failures on a few specific tasks will be listed.

Comment: CoreData would be a good choice to store more complex data object, NSUserDefault is good for very small scale data like 1 type of object, locally generate or not it will also be the same object and you can just treat it the same

Comment: Ok. I'll still have the same problem though, how do I continuously check core data for notification updates? Is there a function I can call to update my notifications tab, and where do I do this from?

Comment: No point for that, once you get the data from server through push, you save it in coredata then at that moment you fetch it's numbers or update or anything

Comment: but what about the local notifications?

Comment: Oh, I guess as soon as it happens, I create a notification?

Comment: Yep, same procedure